# I want to create a Text String in a Parent Object of Multiple Products sold on a specific Opportunity using a Formula Field - Help?

Tags: formula, formula-field, string, if, child-to-parent

Parent Object - Opportunity

Child Object - Opportunity Product

I have a field for each product on the Opportunity.
For example if Opportunity Products X and Y were added to the Opportunity as Opportunity Products on Opportunity fields would state :

Product X=1

PRoduct Y=1

1 indicated products was purchased.

I need to create a formula field that would look up each product's field and if the field is 1 return the name of the product and do it in a string. The issue is if multiple products were purchased the string should return all.

Example
Product X=1
Product Y=1
Product Z=0
Products W=0

New field
Products Purchased = X,Y

I tried to achieve this with IF formulas, but as soon as it evaluated to true it stops checking for other Products. I thought of using the Case formula, but as I understand it works only with retuning numbers.

this is what I have so far, but no idea how to combine it

IF ( Opportunity__r.Product_X >0,"X",

IF( Opportunity__r.Product_Y >0,"Y",

IF( Opportunity__r.Product_Z >0,"Z",

IF(Opportunity__r.Product_W>0,"W",

""))))

Comment: What you are asking for is a concatenation operation across _n_ `OpportunityLineItem`. Rather than have separate fields on Opportunity for each product, use DLRS to rollup the concatenation for you

Comment: A formula field on a parent object cannot pull data from child records.  As cropredy suggests, you'll need a rollup tool.  Also, are you really going to have a separate rollup field for every Product?  That's not scalable.